# How to get the nearest neighbor in weka using java

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, weka, nearest-neighbor

I've been trying to use the Ibk nearest neighbor algorithm that goes together with the weka machine learning library.

I know how to classify instances, but I want to implement the collaborative filtering feature so I need to actually get the list of actual objects that are nearest to the object of interest.

How would I actually do so in weka using its java API?

Comment: Hey there mate I know this is old post but Im trying to implement this for my tesis, and I can't really figure out or understand how to do all this, I was wondering if you could share how can I make the instances and what are them? or share me a link to understand this better, like in my case the data im going to recommend are dishes depending on dishes each user has picked before. But I don't know if each instance is a dish or what? anyways if you could share how to classify instances and what are they its appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this one

```
weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch knn = new LinearNNSearch(
            trainingInstances);
//do other stuff

Instances nearestInstances= knn.kNearestNeighbours(target, 3)
```

Here is the [API documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/neighboursearch/LinearNNSearch.html)  that you can refer to.