# Find best available data in a given data set according to input data using WEKA?

Tags: classification, weka

I tried to use a clear title. What I try to achieve is that I have a list of data as below

ID - ID of people, not important in calculation, but need for output to determine the person
Education {1=Degree, 2=Master, 3=PhD}
CGPA - value from 2.00 until 4.00
Computer = {1=Yes, 0 = No} (Computer knowledge)
Oversea = {1 = Yes, 0 = No} (willing to travel oversea)

ID,Education,CGPA,Computer,Oversea
001,3,3.14,1,0
002,1,3.68,1,1
003,2,2.76,0,1
..........
.........

Say I have 1,000 rows with different values. My purpose is, I want to give similar 1 row of data and get the closest record out of 1,000 rows. I am using WEKA.

I am trying to do something like finding the best resume for a particular job.

I have checked and did many examples to understand better about WEKA, but I just cant get it done. I am new to WEKA. I tried classifiers and decision trees but couldnt. I am able to get the prediction out of given data, but I cannot filter data list according to given input.

Any help much appreciated. Any link that directs me to any article about this, or any idea or even any single sparkle will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a nearest neighbour classifier (`IBk` in Weka). If you're using the Weka GUI, you can only get the class, so you'll have to implement some code to retrieve the actual nearest neighbour.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554796/how-to-actually-get-the-nearest-neighbor-in-weka-using-java) for a way of doing this.